# How to split MIDI file on Linux in command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, midi

Expecting something like

```
split_midi input.mid --from 1:00 --to 2:45 -o output.mid
```

It whould be good if the tool also allow joining, changing volume, filtering tracks and transposing the MIDI.

Answer (score 1):

[MIDI Splitter](http://interglacial.com/~sburke/pub/midi_splitter.pl) can split the file for you, but it can't specify when/where to split or join, change volume etc.

Usage:

`perl Midi_splitter.pl inputfile.mid`

Comment: It splits the file trackwise. I can't extract a fragment of music in MIDI file this way.

Comment: My apologies, I misread your question